# Adding a Rejection field to the approval page layout

Tags: approval-process

I would like to know if there is a way to add a field to the approval page layout. I have already somehow managed to add a field to the layout. But, it's not displaying any output.

The Image is shown below.[image]

If there is a way to display the Rejection- Reason. It would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to sfse -- a few more bits would be helpful -- is rejection reason a custom field on AP Voucher?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom pick-list field on the APVoucher object.

Comment: ok -- i don't think this is supported -- the approval process request layout is readonly fields except for comments which is a built in field used by SFDC Approval Process

Comment: Is there a way I can create such a method.

Comment: not that i know of; best you can do is do field updates on each approval/reject actionstep --but not on the page you referenced in your post. Try posting your question on success.saleforce.com to see if others have an idea

Comment: What I have heard there is also a way to add a custom approval process visualforce page.